# .NET Core Google.Cloud.Firestore Package installed but namespace is missing

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple asp.net core 2.2 project and ran the following to install the Google.Cloud.Firestore package:

```
dotnet add package Google.Cloud.Firestore --version 1.0.0-beta19
```

The package installed correctly and I even verified this by looking at the dll files in the nuget global package store (users/user/.nuget/packages).

The output of the install even has this log:

```
info : Package 'Google.Cloud.Firestore' is compatible with all the specified frameworks in project
```

The following is in my .csprodj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Google.Cloud.Firestore" Version="1.0.0-beta19" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="2.2.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.2.0" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

Yet I get the following upon trying to reference the namespace:

```
The type or namespace name 'Google' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Never really had this problem with any other package installed using the dotnet CLI.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that this is just a matter of the build/IDE getting confused? I've certainly had that in VS before now. If you do a "dotnet restore" and then "dotnet build" do you still see the problem? (As far as I'm aware, the package is fine.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Just tried on a different PC, fresh install of .net core sdk, cloned repo and ran dotnet restore, works fine! Still cant figure out the issue on the other machine but ill keep looking for a solution. Still need to try your suggestion of building the project etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still not sure what the problem was but a restart of the PC did trick ¯_(ツ)_/¯